# How to disable fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to set authorities on my calendar. Only certain users can update the data. While all users can only see the event and are not allowed to make any changes. I'm using `select` function to popup modals. Can fullcalendar be disabled? I want it to be like `readonly` function. Which means all users can read the data. I try to do like this :

```
if(@ViewBag.User == "Admin")
{
editable = true,
}
```

But it doesn't work. The events can still be edited since I also set that attribute inside my JSON codes for events. Is there any way to solve this? Thanks

Comment: just make the fullcalendar `selectable`, `droppable` and `editable` options false - you can use Razor to vary the javascript which is rendered to the page. Of course you still need to make sure this rule is applied on the server side as well (at the methods which are used to save events to your database), because it's easy for a malicious user to bypass any Javascript based restrictions , since every user has access to the developer tools, or to other tools like postman which let you make arbitrary HTTP requests to an endpoint

Comment: And if you're setting editable to true on certain events, perhaps you need to vary that on the server depending on whether the user is admin or not

Comment: @ADyson i'm using your second suggestion since the first one didnt work for me. I put a condition where if the user is not an admin, the event editable is false. It worked well. But it didnt work for selectable function which means the event still can be clicked(showing popup). do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: event clicking is not the same as "selectable" - selectable is for allowing users to create new events by choosing a time. Check the documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectable/). If you don't want events to be clickable then don't render an "eventClick" function into your JS. You didn't mention clicking on events in the question, so I didn't say anything about it before.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
editable = false
```

and set URL for the event as

```
url: '/Event/Create/'
```

if you do not want any redirection to add use below link

```
url: 'Javascript:'
```

User this URL in `events` section. like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable = false,
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            url: 'http://google.com/'
        },
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            url: 'Javascript:'
        }
        // other events here
    ],
    eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.url) {
            window.open(event.url);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: apart from the first line, which OP has already shown, none of the rest of this has anything to do with the question

Comment: @ADyson I have given a full solution.

Comment: It's a solution, sure, but not the solution to the question which was asked. The question mentions nothing about URLs on events, and your handling of the URL in eventClick has nothing to do with making the calendar read-only.